# wc -l not returning correct value

Tags: wc

I have a .txt file that has 10781 lines in it. When I run `wc -l` on the file I get a return of 10780.

If I add a blank line at the end of the .txt I get the correct result of 10781. Can someone explain what exactly `wc -l` counts?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Probably your last line does not have a newline.

See this:

```
$ printf bla > file
$ wc -l file
0 file
```

> $ man 1p wc
>
> -l     Write to the standard output the number of newlines in each input file.

On Unix it's good style to have a newline character at the end of text files. If you can't repair your files you can use these workarounds to count the last "line" always:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038633/wc-l-is-not-counting-last-of-the-file-if-it-does-not-have-end-of-line-character

Comment: ah, yes, that makes sense. Thank you @rudimeier

Comment: At the end of non-empty text files; your 0 length file is how we represent zero lines; if we add a newline, then it contains 1 line. :) I.e. it's a line terminator, not a file terminator.

Comment: "On Unix it's good style to have a newline character at the end of text files." -- The only way a text file can *not* end in newline is if the file is empty. If it ends in any other character, then by definition it is not a text file, due to how POSIX describes what a text file is.

Comment: Actually I guess POSIX defined `wc -l` as is to make sure that  `cat a b | wc -l` is always the same as `wc -l a` + `wc -l b`. Otherwise the output "total count" of `wc -l a b` would be ambiguous.