# When using 'wc \-l' to count the number of file lines, the result is less one

Tags: linux, wc

I want to count the number of file lines, so i use the command `wc -l file`. However, I notice that the result is incorrect which one less than the real number of lines. For example, the number of lines is 96：

[image]

But the result is 95 when using `wc -l`[image]

So what's wrong with the command and is there any other method better to count the number of lines? By the way, my Linux distribution is RedHat and the shell is bash.

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314256/wc-l-not-returning-correct-value  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/553852/70524

Comment: Since it looks like you might be using VSCode, it may interest you to know that VSCode can be configured to insert the final newline whenever you save a file. This ensures that the output of `wc -l FILE` matches your expectations. For how, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704968/visual-studio-code-insert-newline-at-the-end-of-files